# create simple carousel slidler with slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm trying to create a simple carousel slider like the one on the page below which shows rooms in a hostel. Three rooms are displayed at a time in the slider. It's a very common slider setup especially for products etc.

[enter link description here](http://www.imhostels.com/)

I cannot achieve this in revolution slider, each slide takes up all of the slider viewport as it were, I cannot seem to make a slide only take up one -third of the view port so that 3 slides are visible simultaneously. Does anyone know how this is done?
I saw the setting in carousel settings: Max visible items but this makes no difference.
Any help would save my remaining hair!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I realize this may be late, but I figured this out. Under Slider Settings for option 4 (slide layout) you have to set the initial "Layer Grid Size" to something smaller than your screen width. For example, I set mine to 350x200 with 3 max items selected and it is working well. I also have Auto set for the sizing of the slider and all subsequent layers.
[See Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPBqY.png)

Comment: here's some more info and recommended settings for carousel https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/carousel/#carousel-transformations